Is it possible to create dynamic templates for block themes directly from the site editor?
For example, you can create a posts template within the site editor, but how do you make it so that the content for each respective single post displays dynamically?
Here's my single post template code:
<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2 class="wp-block-heading"></h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

I know that I can create PHP templates on the back-end, but do dynamic content tags exist in this context to insert post title and post content to my template on the front-end?

Two block markup examples are the post-title block:
<!-- wp:post-title /-->

and the post-content block:
<!-- wp:post-content /-->

that you can use in your single post template.
See more here under the Query Loop list item:
https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/blocks-list/#theme-blocks
